# Column deductible_amount not getting filled in on table civicrm_line_item

Tags: php, price-sets

We use price fields/line items for all of our contributions.  I noticed that on the line_item table the column deductible_amount is not filling in.  I checked and Price Fields do not seem to have an option for "Is Tax-deductible".  Financial Types do have the check box.

My set up is
Financial Types:

- Donation (tax-deductible is checked)
- Tuition
- Reimbursement

Line Items under Donation:

- General Fund
- Capital Improvement
- Staff Salaries
- Other __________________

What do I do to have it fill in the tax-deductible amount in the line item table?

Answer (score 1):

As you know, financial types can either be deductible or non-deductible. Before the advent of price sets, to record a partially deductible contribution you would use a deductible financial type and then enter in the non-deductible amount. After the advent of price sets, if the overall financial type of a price set is non-deductible, the system will automatically populate the non-deductible amount field for the full amount of the contribution, regardless of whether the individual price field options are configured with deductible financial types.

**What this means is that currently, the system only tracks a non-deductible amount on the contribution level, not on the line item level. The field in the line item table is either a legacy field or a place holder for future use, but it is not something that is currently being populated by the system.**

The demo site is down so I am unable to verify what built in tax tokens are available, but for our clients we instruct them to use a deductible financial type for the price set - in this way, our line-item based tokens will allocate each line item's deductible amount according to the financial type of the price field option.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Comment: As noted in my original posting, I had already checked to see if I had the overall Financial Type was set as deductible. It was. I have the Financial Type "Donation" (Tax-deductible) and the Price Fields listed below that.  It does not seem to carry down into the individual price field options. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi Carl, I was affirming your knowledge of this fact and have edited my response to include a bit more clarity.

Comment: Is this a bug that should be reported?

Comment: In my opinion, it is not a bug, but rather lack of functionality - what you are looking for is tracking a deductible amount on the line item level where currently the system is only tracking it on a contribution level basis.